# How to disable HTTP Method Override in JBoss EAP 7

Tags: java, security, jboss, http-headers

We have a java web app with GWT 2.7 from a vendor and we do NOT have source codes, and this web app deployed in JBoss EAP 7.
Now user use Fortify WebInspect to scan and find a vulnerability **HTTP Method Override**, is there any way to disable or remove http header X-HTTP-METHOD / X-HTTP-Method-Override / X-METHOD-OVERRIDE, just modify config file such as web.xml or JBoss standalone.xml ?

Many thx.

We found a custom code solution about filter, but we hope there's any configuration soluction.

Comment: A servlet filter I think is the only way. You can reject specific methods like: `/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/http-listener=default:list-add(name=disallowed-methods, value="DELETE")`

Answer (score 0):

Open the standalone.xml file in a text editor. Search for the  subsystem. Within the  subsystem, locate the  element(s) that your web app is using. Within the  element, add the following

```
<disallowed-header name="X-HTTP-Method-Override"/>
```

Save and restart.

Comment: We're using JBoss EAP 7.3, and we could not find "disallowed-header" in the offical Model Reference document, could you please give me a sample fragment XML includes "disallowed-header", many thx.

Comment: There is nothing like this: processing those headers is not part of the HTTP server but of the application (or the frameworks it uses). For example Apache CXF has disabled this by default https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-8133.